# модель не сходится на небольшом наборе данных

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Недавно изучаю tensorflow, примеры которые описаны в книгах работают, но в них используются наборы дынных MNIST. Но если я ввожу свои данные микронабор, то модель  не сходится. Ранее я разработал свою сеть и она работала на небольших тестовых наборах не в библиотеке tensorflow. Пример такой подаем на вход массив например `[10,20,30,40]`, а на выход например `[0.1,0.4,0.5]`, то есть на вход `4` нейрона  на выход `3`. Модель обучается, проверяем на вход подаем `[10,20,30,40]` получаем `[0.1,0.4,0.5]`. Но на практике модель не сходится, начинает обучение и затухает. Что не так с организацией сети и входными данными? Похоже на затухающие градиенты, но я не уверен. Как это можно исправить?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation
from sklearn import preprocessing
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10,input_shape=(4,),activation="elu",init="uniform"))
model.add(Dense(10,activation="elu",init="uniform"))
model.add(Dense(3,activation="elu",init="uniform"))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="sgd", metrics=["accuracy"])
def data():
    X = np.array([[40, 80, 30, 60], [100, 40, 20, 80], [90, 190, 10, 15]])
    Y = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [10, 40, 60], [80, 90,100]])
    X=X/100
    Y=Y/100
        return X,Y
x_train,Y_train=data()
model.fit(x_train,Y_train,batch_size=3,epochs=300,
          verbose=1)
a=np.array([40, 80, 30, 60])/100;
predict_dataset = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train,dtype=tf.float32)
reshy =a.reshape((1,- 1))
print("test")
print(reshy)
prediction = model.predict(reshy)
print('prediction')
print(prediction)
print('x_train')
print(x_train)
print('Y_train')
print(Y_tirain)
print("Привет")
```

Comment: что-то у вас здесь все смешалось в кучу... Что данная модель должна предсказывать? Это модель регрессии или классификации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по тензору `Y` у вас задача регрессии. Для задачи регрессии у вас неудачно выбрана функция активации на последнем выходном слое. Кроме того функция потери `loss="categorical_crossentropy"` используется только для задач классификации.

Вот исправленная регрессионная модель:

```
X = np.array([[40, 80, 30, 60], [100, 40, 20, 80], [90, 190, 10, 15]])
Y = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [10, 40, 60], [80, 90,100]])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Adamax', metrics=['mae'])

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=500, verbose=1)
```

Вывод:

```
...
Epoch 498/500
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 669us/step - loss: 4.5900e-07 - mean_absolute_error: 5.2166e-04
Epoch 499/500
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 503us/step - loss: 4.2649e-07 - mean_absolute_error: 5.0259e-04
Epoch 500/500
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 334us/step - loss: 4.0100e-07 - mean_absolute_error: 4.8796e-04
Out[49]: <keras.callbacks.History at 0x1ec427eac88>
```

PS для того чтобы построить более адекватную модель (которая будет не так сильно подвержена переобучению) надо добавить регуляризацию и использовать гораздо больший набор данных для обучения и проверки.

Comment: Спасибо, видимо еще многое предстоит узнать, не предполагал такого ответа.

Comment: @Alexandr1234567890, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)